# Is there a straight forward way to count the number of monomials in a multinomial equation?

Tags: combinatorics, multinomial-coefficients

The [multinomial theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem) states that:

$$(x_1 + x_2 + \dots + x_m)^n = \sum_{k_1 + k_2 + \dots + k_m = n}{n \choose {k_1, k_2, \dots, k_m}}\prod_{1 \le t \le m} {x_t}^{k_t}$$

The number of monomials is the number of solutions to this equation for each $k_i \ge 0$:

$$k_1 + k_2 + \dots + k_m = n$$

Is there a straight forward way to count the number of solutions to the above equation?

Comment: For the record, the summands are indexed by _weak compositions_, in the parlance of enumerative combinatorics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you noted, the number of monomials in the expansion of 
$$(x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_m)^n$$
is the number of solutions in the nonnegative integers of the equation
$$k_1 + k_2 + \cdots + k_m = n$$
where $k_j$ denotes the exponent of $x_j$, $1 \leq j \leq m$.  The number of such solutions is the number of ways $m - 1$ addition signs can be placed in a row of $n$ ones, which is 
$$\binom{n + m - 1}{m - 1}$$
since $m - 1$ of the $n + m - 1$ symbols are addition signs.

Comment: Thanks very much!  I suspected that there was a simple solution.